# How to access ref that was set in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi I have some sort of the following code:

```
class First extends Component {
 constructor(props){super(props)}

 myfunction = () => { this.card //do stuff}

 render() {
  return(
  <Component ref={ref => (this.card = ref)} />
 )}
}
```

Why is it not possible for me to access the `card` in `myfunction`. Its telling me that it is undefined. I tried it with setting a `this.card = React.createRef();` in the constructor but that didn't work either.

Comment: can you show us the full error please ?

Comment: you have one `}` too many

Comment: @MaieonBrix Yes sure. I get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.card.current')`

Comment: Where do you call myFunction?

Comment: can you please show us the exact code ? the error doesn't match your code. Or maybe you forgot to show us how your child component uses this prop ?

Comment: @Qiarash Yes you are right, apologies for that. I am calling the method `myfunction` on the component with `onPress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, it is very likely that your child Component is not using a `forwardRef`, hence the error (from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)). `ref` (in a similar manner to `key`) is not directly accesible by default:

```
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// ☝️ now you can do <MyComponent ref={this.card} />
```

`ref` is, in the end, a DOMNode and should be treated as such, it can only reference an HTML node that will be rendered. You will see it as `innerRef` in some older libraries, which also works without the need for `forwardRef` in case it confuses you:

```
const MyComponent = ({ innerRef, children }) => (
  <button ref={innerRef}>
    {children}
  </button>
));

// ☝️ now you can do <MyComponent innerRef={this.card} />
```

Lastly, if it's a component created by you, you will need to make sure you are passing the ref through `forwardRef` (or the `innerRef`) equivalent. If you are using a third-party component, you can test if it uses either `ref` or `innerRef`. If it doesn't, wrapping it around a `div`, although not ideal, may suffice (but it will not always work):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div ref={this.card}>
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, a bit of explanation on refs and the lifecycle methods, which may help you understand the context better.

**Render does not guarantee that `refs` have been set:**

This is kind of a *chicken-and-egg* problem: you want the component to do something with the **ref** that points to a node, but React hasn't created the node itself. So what can we do?

#### There are two options:

1) If you need to pass the ref to render something else, check first if it's valid:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyComponent ref={this.card} />
      { this.card.current && <OtherComponent target={this.card.current} />
    </>
  );
}
```

2) If you are looking to do some sort of side-effect, `componentDidMount` will guarantee that the **ref** is set:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.card.current) {
      console.log(this.card.current.classList);
  }
}
```

Hope this makes it more clear!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<Component ref={this.card} />`